# I dont get how this lambda function code works

Tags: python, function, lambda

im trying to learn python online and am currently on *lambda functions* but I cant understand this code.  Got the code from w3 school.

```python
def myfunc(n):
  return lambda a : a * n

mydoubler = myfunc(2)

print(mydoubler(11))
```

Ans: 22

I understand the `myfunc(n)`, but isn't `lambda` supposed to have a func written in front of it like `func(n) = lambda n: n+5` or something? Or is the function in front of it just the `func(n)`? And I understand `a*n = 2* 11` in this example but I  don't understand how `2` and `11` slots into `a` and `n` for this example. Any help or explanation will be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
def myfunc(n):
    return lambda a : a * n
```

This creates a new function that accepts one argument, and multiplies that argument (a) by the argument passed to myfunc (n).

```
mydoubler = myfunc(2)
```

Therefore, this creates a new function that accepts one argument, and multiplies that argument by 2.

```
mydoubler(11)
```

This calls the new function with an argument of 11.

11 * 2 = 22.

Honestly, if you're just starting to learn python, there are easier things you could study than lambdas...